# The fastest Gröbner basis algorithm available?

Tags: soft-question, cryptography, math-software, symbolic-computation, groebner-basis

for my undergraduate thesis I'm (pseudo) replicating algebraic attack on certain cryptosystem using gröbner basis approach. The heart of original attack was F5/2 algorithm (since the cryptosystem is defined over $GF(2)$), which I appear to have no access to - I am aware of no public implementation of this algorithm. 
As the original computation was pretty tough - 2 days on regular PC time, it is important to get as effective algorithm as possible for computing such a gröbner basis.

I'd be very pleased if any could provide advice in choosing fast implementation of algorithm for computing gröbner basis.

Thank you.

Comment: Most of the CAS have a fast Groebner algorithm implemented. Very effective is to sort out "obvious" solutions; this can speed up the computation considerably, but depends very much on the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Magma, which has special code for dense systems:
http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/users/allan/densef4/